# JavaScript not working properly in a To-Do List Project

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm working on this simple project. It's a To-Do List. Every task has to buttons, namely, done and delete (These are images). And there are two divisions, one will store the pending tasks and the other will stored the completed tasks.

I want that when the user clicks on the done button (tick image) the task should be removed from the "Pending Tasks" division and shifted to the "Completed Tasks" division. I tried to add this functionality by adding an event listener to the images. The event listens for a single click. But the code is not working properly. For the first task, I've to click twice to remove it. The same is the case with other tasks as well. Which means every single task is added twice to the "Completed Tasks" division.

Also, I've added functionality to add new tasks. But the buttons (images) don't work on these new tasks. Basically, event listening is not working on them. Kindly help with the issue. I've added the code below.

(I've not added any functionality for deletion)

```js
var completedTasks = document.querySelector(".Completed-Tasks");
var pendingTasks = document.querySelector(".Pending-Tasks");
var addTaskButton = document.querySelector(".Add-Task-Button");
var doneButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".Tick");
var deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".Cross");

doneButtons.forEach(checkClickEvent);
console.log(doneButtons.length);

function checkClickEvent(button, index) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let task = button.parentNode.parentNode;
        pendingTasks.removeChild(pendingTasks.childNodes[index]);
        let doneTaskHTML = `<div class="Task Done"><p class="Task-Text">${task.children[0].textContent}</p><div class="Task-Operations"><img src="./Cross.png" alt="Delete" class="Operation"></div></div>`;
        completedTasks.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", doneTaskHTML);
    });
}

addTaskButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let newTaskText = document.querySelector(".Add-Task-Input");

    if (newTaskText.value != "") {
        let newTaskHTML = `<div class="Task"><p class="Task-Text">${newTaskText.value}</p><div class="Task-Operations"><img src="./Tick.png" alt="Done" class="Operation Tick"><img src="./Cross.png" alt="Delete" class="Operation Cross"></div></div>`;
        pendingTasks.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", newTaskHTML);
        newTaskText.value = "";
    }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins";
}

body {
    background: #EDF2F4;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.Header {
    background: #2B2D42;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.Heading {
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

.Tasks-Space {
    background: #8D99AE;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

.Add-Task {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.Add-Task-Input {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.Add-Task-Button {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #D90429;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.Add-Task-Button:hover {
    background: #EF233C;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.Tasks-Space-Heading {
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #2B2D42;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.Pending-Tasks {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.Completed-Tasks {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.Task {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.Task-Operations {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.Operation {
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.Done {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To-Do List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Header">
        <p class="Heading">TO-DO LIST</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Tasks-Space">
        <div class="Add-Task">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your task here" class="Add-Task-Input">
            <button class="Add-Task-Button">Add Task</button>
        </div>
        <p class="Tasks-Space-Heading">Pending Tasks</p>
        <div class="Pending-Tasks">
            <div class="Task">
                <p class="Task-Text">Make a pie</p>
                <div class="Task-Operations">
                    <img src="./Tick.png" alt="Done" class="Operation Tick">
                    <img src="./Cross.png" alt="Delete" class="Operation Cross">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Task">
                <p class="Task-Text">Play Minecraft</p>
                <div class="Task-Operations">
                    <img src="./Tick.png" alt="Done" class="Operation Tick">
                    <img src="./Cross.png" alt="Delete" class="Operation Cross">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="Tasks-Space-Heading">Completed Tasks</p>
        <div class="Completed-Tasks"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `pendingTasks.removeChild(pendingTasks.childNodes[index]);` do `task.remove();` since you already have the node that you want to remove. here is the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove#using_remove) to `remove()` function.

Also added `document.querySelectorAll(".Tick").forEach(checkClickEvent);` in add task click handler. This should add event listener to newly added tasks as well.

**Edited**

The solution did work but there was a slight problem. When we are adding event listeners to the new tasks using `document.querySelectorAll(".Tick").forEach(checkClickEvent);`, multiple event listeners are getting added to the existing tasks. To avoid this simply reinitialize the HTML inside the division. This can be done using `pendingTasks.innerHTML = pendingTasks.innerHTML;`. This code will remove all the existing event listeners on any element inside the division. Note that this code has to be used before adding event listeners again.

```js
var completedTasks = document.querySelector(".Completed-Tasks");
var pendingTasks = document.querySelector(".Pending-Tasks");
var addTaskButton = document.querySelector(".Add-Task-Button");
var doneButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".Tick");
var deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".Cross");

doneButtons.forEach(checkClickEvent);
console.log(doneButtons.length);

function checkClickEvent(button, index) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let task = button.parentNode.parentNode;
    task.remove();
    let doneTaskHTML = `<div class="Task Done"><p class="Task-Text">${task.children[0].textContent}</p><div class="Task-Operations"><img src="./Cross.png" alt="Delete" class="Operation"></div></div>`;
    completedTasks.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", doneTaskHTML);
  });
}

addTaskButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let newTaskText = document.querySelector(".Add-Task-Input");

  if (newTaskText.value != "") {
    let newTaskHTML = `<div class="Task"><p class="Task-Text">${newTaskText.value}</p><div class="Task-Operations"><img src="./Tick.png" alt="Done" class="Operation Tick"><img src="./Cross.png" alt="Delete" class="Operation Cross"></div></div>`;
    pendingTasks.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", newTaskHTML);
    newTaskText.value = "";
    pendingTasks.innerHTML = pendingTasks.innerHTML; // Re-initialize
    document.querySelectorAll(".Tick").forEach(checkClickEvent); // Adding event listeners again
  }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}

body {
  background: #EDF2F4;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.Header {
  background: #2B2D42;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.Heading {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Tasks-Space {
  background: #8D99AE;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.Add-Task {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.Add-Task-Input {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.Add-Task-Button {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #D90429;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.Add-Task-Button:hover {
  background: #EF233C;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.Tasks-Space-Heading {
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #2B2D42;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.Pending-Tasks {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.Completed-Tasks {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.Task {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.Task-Operations {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.Operation {
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>To-Do List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Header">
    <p class="Heading">TO-DO LIST</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Tasks-Space">
    <div class="Add-Task">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your task here" class="Add-Task-Input">
      <button class="Add-Task-Button">Add Task</button>
    </div>
    <p class="Tasks-Space-Heading">Pending Tasks</p>
    <div class="Pending-Tasks">
      <div class="Task">
        <p class="Task-Text">Make a pie</p>
        <div class="Task-Operations">
          <img src="./Tick.png" alt="Done" class="Operation Tick">
          <img src="./Cross.png" alt="Delete" class="Operation Cross">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Task">
        <p class="Task-Text">Play Minecraft</p>
        <div class="Task-Operations">
          <img src="./Tick.png" alt="Done" class="Operation Tick">
          <img src="./Cross.png" alt="Delete" class="Operation Cross">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="Tasks-Space-Heading">Completed Tasks</p>
    <div class="Completed-Tasks"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you help with the other problem as well? When new tasks are added they are not getting removed.

Comment: @vaibhav I've Updated the answer. called function to add event listener after appending the new task.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```js
// Create a "close" button and append it to each list item
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
}

// Click on a close button to hide the current list item
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function(data) {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
      var data = div.innerText;
    var list = document.getElementById("list");;
       var firstname = div.value;
var entry = document.createElement('li');
entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
list.appendChild(entry);

  }

}

// Add a "checked" symbol when clicking on a list item
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);

// Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button
function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);

  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 250px;
  font-family: arial;
}

/* Include the padding and border in an element's total width and height */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Remove margins and padding from the list */
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Style the list items */
ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* make the list items unselectable */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/* When clicked on, add a background color and strike out text */
ul li.checked {
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */
ul li.checked::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 15px;
  width: 7px;
}

/* Style the close button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}

/* Style the header */
.header {
  background-color: #f44336;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Clear floats after the header */
.header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Style the input */
input {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}

 input[type=text] {
outline: 0;
background: #eee;
border: 0;
transition: all .2s;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);}
/* Style the "Add" button */
.addBtn {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  color: #555;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.addBtn:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="myDIV" class="header">
  <h2 style="margin:5px">My To Do List</h2>
  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Title..." autocomplete="off">
  <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
</div>

<ul id="myUL">
  <li>Hit the gym</li>
  <li>Pay bills</li>
  <li>Meet George</li>
  <li>Buy eggs</li>
  <li>Read a book</li>
  <li>Organize office</li>
</ul>
<p style="padding-left: 30px;">Completed Tasks</p>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: This does not add the task to completed list. it simply removes it. and here is the code ref https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_todolist.asp.

Comment: Hi! I have edited the post, could you try it out?